# Custom font color tool in Kendo Editor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I want to know if it´s possible to remove some colors in font color tool of the Kendo Editor ...
actually I have this.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Editor()
                .Name("Editor")
                .Tools(tools => tools.Clear().FontColor())
                .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "some_class" })
                .Events(e => e.Change("someEvent"))
    )
```

I need only allow red and green colors.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code,

Below code execute in page load event.
 in if condition you have to display which color is displayed

```
    $(".k-palette,.k-reset").find('ul.k-palette').find('li').each(function () {
                if ($(this).attr('aria-label') === "#ffccff") 
{            
                    $(this).css('display','block');
                }
                else { $(this).css('display', 'none'); }
            });
```